# Shortcut for Chrome inspect

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, web-inspector

I just rediscovered inspect() in chrome console. It would be a lot easier and faster to find elements with Inspect, but this is tedious even with a tool like TextExpander:

```
inspect(document.getElementsByClassName('overlay-thumbs')[0])
// Or if jQuery is active
inspect(jQuery('.overlay-thumbs').get(0))
```

Is there a way to set up some snippet/function to just do ( for example ):

```
goTo('.overlay-thumbs')
goTo('#mySelector')
```

That would speed up everything up quite a bit!

I know chrome supports Snippets, but I still haven't figured out how exactly do they work and if they're even relevant to what I want right now...

Comment: So `goTo(X)` is `inspect(document.querySelector(X))`, right?

Comment: Kind of, yeah. I could live with two separate functions ( goTo and goToID ).

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools mentions that `inspectedWindow.eval()` has access to the console API. So, a devtools extensions seems to be the way to go.